# How can form data be stored in the database and mailed to a email id at the same time using node/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express, backend

I am developing a website using express/node.It contains a form whose data I am storing it in a mySQL database.
Is there any way that the form can be mailed to an email id along with it getting stored in the database using node/html/express.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Yes, it can be done, but what is it you have specifically problems with? Questions that address a specific programming problem are easier to answer. See also: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You could use mailx or mail or exim4 if under linux after successful storage in your db: `shell.exec('echo "This mail was sent from: ${from}. Message: ${messsage}" | mail -s "${subject}" ${to} -aFrom:sysadm@foobar.net');`